# Debian Farstream dependencies

Tags: debian, apt, pidgin

I am having trouble getting pidgin to build from source. Running the ./autogen.sh

I fail on not finding FARSTREAM but I have that package installed.

```
blubee@naibed:~/Development/pidgin-main$ sudo aptitude search farstream
i A gir1.2-farstream-0.1                                                    - Audio/Video communications framework: GObject-Introspection                      
i A gir1.2-farstream-0.2                                                    - Audio/Video communications framework: GObject-Introspection                      
i A libfarstream-0.1-0                                                      - Audio/Video communications framework: core library                               
p   libfarstream-0.1-dbg                                                    - Audio/Video communications framework: debugging symbols                          
i   libfarstream-0.1-dev                                                    - Audio/Video communications framework: development files                          
p   libfarstream-0.1-doc                                                    - Audio/Video communications framework: documentation                              
i A libfarstream-0.2-2                                                      - Audio/Video communications framework: core library                               
p   libfarstream-0.2-dbg                                                    - Audio/Video communications framework: debugging symbols                          
i   libfarstream-0.2-dev                                                    - Audio/Video communications framework: development files                          
p   libfarstream-0.2-doc                                                    - Audio/Video communications framework: documentation                              
i   libtelepathy-farstream-dev                                              - Glue library between telepathy and farstream (development files)                 
p   libtelepathy-farstream-doc                                              - Glue library between telepathy and farstream (documentation)                     
i A libtelepathy-farstream3                                                 - Glue library between telepathy and farstream                                     
p   libtelepathy-farstream3-dbg                                             - Glue library between telepathy and farstream (debug symbols)                     
p   libtelepathy-qt4-farstream2                                             - Telepathy/Farsight integration - Qt 4 library                                    
p   python-farstream                                                        - Audio/Video communications framework: Python bindings                            
v   python2.7-farstream                                                     -
```

as you can see from my aptitude search i've installed everything debian recommends for farstream but I still get the build error.

```
checking for JSON... yes
checking for ZLIB... yes
checking for gconftool-2... /usr/bin/gconftool-2
Using config source xml:merged:/etc/gconf/gconf.xml.defaults for schema installation
Using $(sysconfdir)/gconf/schemas as install directory for schema files
checking for GSTREAMER... yes
checking for GSTVIDEO... yes
checking for FARSTREAM... no
configure: error: 
Dependencies for voice/video were not met.
Install the necessary gstreamer and farstream packages first.
Or use --disable-vv if you do not need voice/video support.
```

also I have already installed all the gstreamer plugins

```
i   gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad                                                - GStreamer plugins from the "bad" set                                             
i   gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad-dbg                                            - GStreamer plugins from the "bad" set (debug symbols)                             
i   gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad-doc                                            - GStreamer documentation for plugins from the "bad" set                           
i   gstreamer1.0-plugins-base                                               - GStreamer plugins from the "base" set                                            
i   gstreamer1.0-plugins-base-apps                                          - GStreamer helper programs from the "base" set                                    
i   gstreamer1.0-plugins-base-dbg                                           - GStreamer plugins from the "base" set                                            
i   gstreamer1.0-plugins-base-doc                                           - GStreamer documentation for plugins from the "base" set                          
i   gstreamer1.0-plugins-good                                               - GStreamer plugins from the "good" set                                            
i   gstreamer1.0-plugins-good-dbg                                           - GStreamer plugins from the "good" set                                            
i   gstreamer1.0-plugins-good-doc                                           - GStreamer documentation for plugins from the "good" set                          
i   gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly                                               - GStreamer plugins from the "ugly" set                                            
i   gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly-dbg                                           - GStreamer plugins from the "ugly" set (debug symbols)                            
i   gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly-doc                                           - GStreamer documentation for plugins from the "ugly" set
```

I've been doing apt-cache and aptitude search but can't figure out what's missing. What am I missing?

Answer (score -2):

`pidgin 2.10.11-1` is packaged for debian already (for `wheezy`, `jessie`, `testing`, and `sid`.  2.7.3 is in `squeeze`, and 2.10.10 is in `squeeze-backports`).  and so are a large number of pidgin-related packages

```
$ apt-cache search -n pidgin
pidgin-skype - Skype plugin for libpurple messengers (Pidgin-specific files)
pidgin-skype-common - Skype plugin for libpurple messengers (common files)
pidgin-skype-dbg - Skype plugin for libpurple messengers (debug symbols)
pidgin-themes - Smiley themes collection for pidgin
pidgin-guifications - toaster popups for pidgin
indicator-status-provider-pidgin - indicator-messages status provider for pidgin
pidgin - graphical multi-protocol instant messaging client for X
pidgin-data - multi-protocol instant messaging client - data files
pidgin-dbg - Debugging symbols for Pidgin
pidgin-dev - multi-protocol instant messaging client - development files
pidgin-audacious - pidgin integration with Audacious
pidgin-awayonlock - pidgin plugin to set as away on screensaver activation
pidgin-blinklight - Blinks your ThinkPad's ThinkLight upon new messages
pidgin-encryption - pidgin plugin that provides transparent encryption
pidgin-extprefs - extended preferences plugin for the instant messenger pidgin
pidgin-festival - pidgin plugin to hear incoming messages using voice synthesis
pidgin-gmchess - pidgin integration with gmchess
pidgin-gnome-keyring - integrates pidgin (and libpurple) with the system keyring
pidgin-gnome-keyring-dbg - debugging symbols for pidgin-gnome-keyring
pidgin-hotkeys - Configurable global hotkeys for pidgin
pidgin-lastfm - Last.fm plugin for Pidgin
pidgin-latex - Pidgin plugin to display LaTeX formulas
pidgin-libnotify - display notification bubbles in pidgin
pidgin-librvp - MS Exchange RVP instant messaging plugin for Pidgin
pidgin-microblog - Microblogging plugins for Pidgin
pidgin-microblog-dbg - Microblogging plugins for Pidgin (debugging symbols)
pidgin-mpris - sets your available message to your currently playing track
pidgin-mra - Mail.ru Agent protocol plugin for Pidgin IM
pidgin-mra-dbg - Mail.ru Agent protocol plugin for Pidgin IM
pidgin-nateon - Pidgin plugin for NateOn instant messaging service
pidgin-nateon-dbg - debugging symbols of pidgin-nateon
pidgin-openfetion - Fetion protocol plugin for libpurple
pidgin-openpgp - OpenPGP plugin for Pidgin
pidgin-otr - Off-the-Record Messaging plugin for Pidgin
pidgin-privacy-please - plugin for enhanced privacy in pidgin
pidgin-sipe - Pidgin plugin for MS Office Communicator and MS Lync
pidgin-sipe-dbg - Pidgin plugin for MS Office Communicator and MS Lync (debug symbols)
pidgin-twitter - Pidgin plugin for Twitter
pidgin-plugin-pack - Collection of Pidgin plugins
```

If you really need to build your own local version, download the debian source package (e.g. with `apt-get source pidgin`), modify the source, and build a package or package(s).

Comment: this is a bit helpful to see all the packages but if I was trying to build another program not available in in official repos, how could I solve the issue of missing packages?

Comment: install the build-deps for `pidgin`, probably `pidgin-dev` too.  build a local package (e.g. using `debdry` and `debhelper`).  Also check the contents of `pidgin-plugin-pack` just in case it's already in there.

Comment: btw, one common mistake that people make is not realising that the `libfoo` package ONLY contains the runtime files (e.g. .so libs).  If you want to compile programs using that lib, you need to install the `libfoo-dev` package, which contains the header and .a library.

Comment: See also: https://wiki.debian.org/DontBreakDebian